# Array Modification from 3D to 2D while Removing Data

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Sorry if this seems like a basic question, but I'm struggling here... I've got a 3-Dimensional array in Python that I only want to pull some data from, going from 3D to 2D. This is not a reshape.

I'm beginning with a 3D array (2x3x5):

```
a = [[[0  0  0  0  0]
      [1  1  1  1  1]
      [2  2  2  2  2]]

     [[1  2  3  4  5]
      [2  3  4  5  6]
      [3  4  5  6  7]]]
```

I'm trying to extract a 2D array (2x5) from the above:

```
b = [[0  0  0  0  0]
     [1  2  3  4  5]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's not even valid Python syntax. For one thing, lists must be comma separated. For another, you have an assignment to `a` of a list of three lists of 5 elements each, followed by a second, non-assigned list of three lists of 5 elements. Try fixing those issues first, so it's a bit more clear what you're attempting to do...

Comment: Bracket issue fixed.

Comment: It's still invalid syntax, but perhaps something like `[ x[0] for x in a ]` would be what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out...

I had been trying `a[:][0][:]`, when I simply needed `a[:,0,:]`